# What are some steps you would consider when conducting a major code upgrade to Juniper equipment in a production environment?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I am responsible for a project conducting a major code upgrade on our core/aggregation and distribution layer switches along with our ISP routers.

We run all Juniper Routers and switches minus a few stray Arista switches used for aggregation.

Ive already done most of the keg work, and research on the actual processes involved in this but my question is this.

When I cut over to my secondary routing engine on the MX80s which will be our first portion of the project, should I expect to see any sort of packet loss or service interruption? I am aware that making the secondary RE is supposed to avert this, however this will be my first major upgrade in a large production environment.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ty,

check out ISSU options on the code version you have on the MX's

http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos14.2/topics/reference/requirements/issu-system-requirements.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on all stack exchange sites, please consider adding more details to your answer.